# Is there a way of telling when std::future is finished?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing

I'm trying to optimize my application. Basically I have a class A that has members

```
std::vector< B* >       bvec;
std::vector<std::future<void> > futures;
```

Where B is another class.

In one of the methods of the A class I have a for loop that uses the Update method from the B class to update all elements of the bvec:

```
for (auto* b : bvec) {
    b->Update(bvec);
}
```

I want to do that faster and that's why I changed it to:

```
for (auto* b : bvec) {
    futures.push_back(std::async(std::launch::async, update, b, bvec));
}
```

Where:

```
void update(B* b, const std::vector< B* >& vec) {
    b->Update(vec);
}
```

(I tried to write it as a lambda but I failed)

In the A class I have a method that on a key-pressed, removes a certain amount of the objects:

```
void A::removeObjects( int numObjects )
    while (numObjects-- && !bvec.empty())
    {
        delete bvec.back();
        bvec.pop_back();
    }
}
```

The program stops working when for example I start with 10 objects in the bvec and I use the A::removeObjects method to remove 5 objects. I figured it's because not all the work is done in Update and I cannot remove those objects in that moment. What I want to do is to wait until the futures tasks are finished and that's why I added a line under the for loop:

```
futures[futures.size() - 1].wait();
```

I don't know if that's a good idea to check only the last element of the vector. Anyways, it works but now the problem is that it really slows down the app. It's faster than withot std::future but much slower than without checking (the method with the .wait() is inside a loop so it has a lot of waiting to do). What I want to do is to check if everything is done while removing objects (in the A::removeObjects) but then I get Access violation reading location error.

Is there any other way to check the futures before removing objects?

Comment: What is expected behaviour when you want to remove `B` object for which `Update` is asynchronously ongoing? `Update` should be interrupted, aborted, finished normally? Are results from `Update` discarded anyway?

Comment: @R2RT Update should be finished normally.

Comment: If you need the ability to "cancel" a async launched task issue by ```std::async```, you can implement your own timeout strategy in ```update```, like using an atomic flag or something